trouble linking css to html
I have a project I am working on and my css styling doesn't appear when i go live. I have linked it to my html however the styling still doessn't appear on the browser when I am live
I have inspected the webpage itself and the css is there however I can't seem to figure out the problem
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>   
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title> Mind Connect </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: poppins;

}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
}

#hero{
    background-color: #f5f7fb;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 600px;

}

.navigation{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 1200px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 30px 0px;



I have inspected the webpage itself and the css is there — can you please edit your post to include a screenshot of your inspector or however you are deciding that "the CSS is there"?

I am not eligible as of yet toadd images, I am new here :(

@Lee if you are on Windows, you can show your directory/file structure using the tree /f command. Ref

Your href attribute is using a path relative to your HTML file. Is the css folder located in a folder where you serve public assets, typically called assets or public? If so, to correctly reference the file the href must start with a slash, so /css/styles.css.
If that is not the problem, then it may be because the css folder is not exposed to the client, so you would need to put it in a static assets folder that is exposed to the client.
(I would have just written a comment, but I don't have enough reputation yet.)
